# MAUI Tabbed Page crashes when it is called from another page

Tags: maui, tabbedpage

Simple example
Main Page (which is a simple content page with a button)
Second Page (which is the tabbed page displayed when the button is pressed)

The code works under Windows, but on Android crashes during startup with "fragment viewid not found"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
          x:Class="TabbedMaui.MainPage"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TabbedMaui" 
      >
<Button
    Text="Go" Clicked="Button_Clicked"></Button>
ed</ContentPage>
```

The second page is shown in the code block

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="TabbedMaui.SecondPage"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TabbedMaui" 
        x:DataType="local:SecondPage"
             Title="Some title" BackgroundColor="blue">
<ContentPage Title="Page 1" BackgroundColor="Red">
    <VerticalStackLayout >
        <Label Text="Hello"></Label>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
             </ContentPage>
<ContentPage Title="Page 2" BackgroundColor="Yellow"></ContentPage>
<ContentPage Title="Page 3"></ContentPage>
</TabbedPage>
```

Comment: May I confirm that is the `MainPage` a Shell-based `ContentPage`?

Comment: For clarity, add to question the contents of `Button_Clicked` method.

Comment: The Main Page is Shell Based. namespace TabbedMaui;

public partial class App : Application
{
 public App()
 {
  InitializeComponent();
  MainPage = new AppShell();
 }
}

Answer (score 1):

This issue can be reproduced here. And it is a known issue that being tracked in the link below, you can follow up there.

https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/7615

Currently, you cannot mix [TabbedPage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/pages/tabbedpage) together with `MAUI Shell` as the official docs states clearly below:

> TabbedPage is incompatible with .NET MAUI Shell apps, and an
> exception will be thrown if you attempt to use TabbedPage in a Shell
> app.

As an alternative workaround, you may be able to set the `App.MainPage` to a `TabbedPage` to get it resolved.

Comment: Yes I did notice the documentation, but interestingly the code does work on Windows. It crashes on Android. The code also works if the tabbed page is the Main Page, it just does not work when the tabbed page is called from the main page

Comment: @BrendenJacobson Thanks for the response! Yes, it's a known issue that happens on Android, you may need to follow up with the thread:https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/7615